# CSS: group same class

Tags: html, css

I have a reservation html table in which you can change selected order reservation time (see image below)

1 TD = 1 Hour. If order makes a reservation for 3 hours, 3 TD fills with word "Selected".

Question: How could I group them or select via css, so that I could target for example first and last childs in order to merge TD's by removing some borders in CSS. I have tried

`:nth-child()`, `:first-child` and `:last-child` - did not work.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to modify the first cell's `rowspan` attribute based on the number of following selected cells.

Comment: use rowspan attribute in html

Comment: Please add markup and css to your question, and elaborate on the exact versions you've tried. Help us [repro](http://sscce.org) the issue.

Comment: Well, code isn't flexible at all (it's a copy paste). I can try to get use of `roswpan` (how I forgot that) based on count of reserved hours array, but then I will have to think of how to hide every selected TD after first one. I will let you know how it turned out. Thank you